# Is there any difference between Ruby 'AES-128-CBC' and PHP 'rijndael-128' encryption?

Tags: php, ruby, encryption, cryptography

Ruby code is

```
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'

def ruby_dec iv, key, encrypted
  decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC)
  #decipher.padding = 0 
  decipher.decrypt
  decipher.key = key
  decipher.iv = iv
  ciphertext = Base64.decode64 encrypted
  decipher.update(ciphertext) + decipher.final
end


def ruby_enc iv, key, plaintext 
  enc = OpenSSL::Cipher.new 'aes-128-cbc'
  enc.encrypt
  enc.key = key
  enc.iv = iv

  Base64.encode64(enc.update(plaintext) + enc.final)
end

iv = Base64.decode64("TOB+9YNdXSbkSYIU7D/IpQ==")
key =  Base64.decode64("7DxoShENB0D+8xrwOwSbi1TPQBiIaFq2yveoUkutCpM=")
plaintext = "testtesttest"

encrypted = ruby_enc iv, key, plaintext
puts "encrypted is #{encrypted}"
ruby_dec iv, key, encrypted
puts "plaintext is #{plaintext}"
```

then

```
$ ruby enc_dec.rb #the above code
encrypted is LXJmnM7t+HGKi2iI51ethA==
plaintext is testtesttest
```

Now PHP code is

```
function php_dec($iv, $key, $encrypted) { 
  $cipher_algorithm    = 'rijndael-128';
  $cipher_mode = 'cbc';

  $key = base64_decode($key);
  $iv = base64_decode($iv);
  $ciphertext = base64_decode($enctypted);
  return $ciphertext;
}


function php_enc($iv, $key, $plaintext){
  $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

  $mcrypt_key = base64_decode($key);
  $iv = base64_decode($iv);
  mcrypt_generic_init($td, $mcrypt_key, $iv);

  $ciphertext = mcrypt_generic($td, $plaintext);

  retun base64_encode($ciphertext); 
}

$iv = base64_decode("TOB+9YNdXSbkSYIU7D/IpQ==");
$key =  base64_decode("7DxoShENB0D+8xrwOwSbi1TPQBiIaFq2yveoUkutCpM=");
$plaintext = "testtesttest";

$encrypted = php_enc($iv, $key, $plaintext);
echo "encrypted is ".$encrypted."\n";
php_dec($iv, $key, $encrypted);
echo "plaintext is ".$plaintext."\n";

$ruby_encrypted = base64_encode("LXJmnM7t+HGKi2iI51ethA==");
php_dec($iv, $key, $ruby_encrypted);
echo "plaintext is ".$plaintext."\n";
```

then I get

```
$ php enc_dec.php
encrypted is SUR33tXu32JjR9JAKIGL7w==
plaintext is testtesttest
plaintext is testtesttest
```

the ciphertext is different from the ruby one.
Now I try to decrypt ruby with cipher text made by PHP.

```
$ pry
  [1] pry(main)> load 'enc_dec.rb'
  [2] pry(main)> iv = Base64.decode64("TOB+9YNdXSbkSYIU7D/IpQ==")    
  => "L\xE0~\xF5\x83]]&\xE4I\x82\x14\xEC?\xC8\xA5"
  [3] pry(main)> key =  Base64.decode64("7DxoShENB0D+8xrwOwSbi1TPQBiIaFq2yveoUkutCpM=")    
  => "\xEC<hJ\x11\r\a@\xFE\xF3\x1A\xF0;\x04\x9B\x8BT\xCF@\x18\x88hZ\xB6\xCA\xF7\xA8RK\xAD\n\x93"
  [4] pry(main)> ruby_dec iv, key, Base64.decode64("SUR33tXu32JjR9JAKIGL7w==")
  OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: data not multiple of block length
  from enc_dec.rb:12:in `final'
  [5] pry(main)>
```

Is there any difference between Ruby 'AES-128-CBC' and PHP 'rijndael-128' encryption?
and how can i decrypt with ruby?

Comment: Could you remove your previous question about the same thing? Note that you should *edit* your question if you just want to provide more information.

Comment: Thank you your comment, I deleted previous one. and from next time I do edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between AES and Rijndael in the meaning of 128, in AES the 128 is the keysize, in Rijndael it is the blocksize.

The key you used is larger than 128 bits I believe.

See this article:
http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2014/02/aes-php-mcrypt-key-padding/

Comment: Thank you your comment, the PHP encryption key size is 32Byte.

Comment: If PHP encryption with 32 Byte, I should decrypt with AES-256-CBC right?

Comment: I got it about key size and the number included in their name. and tried with AES-256-CBC, I can decrypt successfully!!Thanks a lot!